# sql check if not record exists before insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables with exactly the same columns

## Table : A (Schedule)

```
 id          Date        From             TO
----------- ----------  ---------------- ----------------
1           2014-04-10  08:00:00         09:00:00
2           2014-04-10  09:10:00         10:10:00
3           2014-04-10  14:00:00         15:00:00
4           2014-04-10  08:30:00         09:30:00
5           2014-04-12  18:00:00         19:00:00
```

## Table : B (Group)

```
ID          Name
----------- ----------
1           name_1
2           name_2
3           name_3
```

## Table : C (Join)

```
ID          GroupID     ScheduleID
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           1           2
3           1           3
```

I want to know how can I insert 4th record from table A into table C if it does not exist table A.[from] between from and to (Time) preview records in table C.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? At this moment the requirement is not very clear. Why only the 4th record why not the 5th one ? What do you mean by "I want to know how can I insert 4th record from table A into table C if it does not exist table A.[from] between from and to preview records in table C."

Comment: I suggest you do things in easy stages. Build your query little by little as long as you know what to do. Once you've come across a stumbling block, feel free to ask about it but then please **post what you've got so far**. At this point your question really sounds as a *‘Do my job for me’* request, which has *never* been the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on what criteria you are defining in: `insert 4th record from table A into table C if it does not exist table A.[from] between from and to preview records` is but default statement to check if something exists is below.

```
INSERT INTO C
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.ID = C.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the tables are designed to do the following:

- **Table A** holds schedule information. Schedule 1, therefore, seems to be indicate that something is scheduled between 8AM and 9AM on April 10th.
- **Table B** holds the names of various groups to be scheduled per the information held in Table A.
- **Table C** is the [intersection table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to map groups to schedules.

Ideally, the ID column in each table would be an auto-incrementing unique primary key. This would enable you to insert a new record into Table C without checking first whether a record with ID 4 already exists.

As for the actual `INSERT` statement, an `INSERT INTO C SELECT .. FROM A` would not work as the columns in Table A and Table C do not match.

Which group are you trying to assign to a schedule? If it was `name_1`, you could use the following statement.

```
INSERT INTO C
SELECT 4, 1, 4
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE ID = 4)
```